# Why does the PHP manual claim that "Process IDs are not unique"?

Tags: php

I don't fully understand this documentation: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getmypid.php

> Warning
> Process IDs are not unique, thus they are a weak entropy source. We recommend against relying on pids in security-dependent contexts.

Okay? So... does that mean that I shouldn't use `getmypid()`, then? How do I get the *unique* process id rather than this (apparently) fake process id which is for some reason not unique? And what does it even mean that it's "not unique"?

All I wanna know is the assigned id of the current PHP CLI script, so that I can update my database table keeping track of their memory usage.

Comment: Which parts of the sentence are unclear to you? Reading the process ID sounds fine, the documentation only states tht you should not use it for security stuff

Comment: These IDs are not unique - that solely means that two processes started at distinct times could use the same ID

Comment: @NicoHaase How can that be possible? And doesn't that make the "PID" useless?

Comment: "(apparently) fake process id " - where does the documentation state anything related to this?

Comment: "How can that be possible?" - what exactly? Please edit your question if you want to clarify it. Don't use the comment section for important information

Comment: @user17535142 read again Nico's comment : *"two processes started at distinct times"*

Comment: Also, if you read over parts in the documentation that are unclear, you could try to improve it. PHP itself and the documentation are open-source projects that are only as good as the people who contribute to it

Comment: "***...so that I can update my database table keeping track of their memory usage.***" Think about what will happen if your server restarts. Those PIDs might not be the same now...

Comment: @Bossman Well, I clear it.

Answer (score 4):

At every point in time the process ids of the processes are unique. But this property vanishes if you consider a time span. This is the underlying reason to state that pids aren't unique.

It is true though, that while your process is running, there won't exist another process with the same pid, no matter how long your process runs.

In order to uniquely identify a process within a period of time, you are going to need a time reference as well. The start time of the process could serve this purpose, even if it can't be exactly determined. But the start time up to a minute will be sufficient. Especially now that with the newer kernels the pid is a 4 byte int. It'll be hard to start 2 billion processes within a minute.

Comment: Well, if it's unique "at any given time", that's unique to me. This does *not* at all come across in the warning box.

Comment: @user17535142 If there are no duplicate pids at any point in time, this does not tell you anything about the pids if you compare the lists of used pids at two different points in time. The list `(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)` consists of unique numbers only, but the two lists `(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)` and `(2, 7, 9, 13)` show a duplicate pid and it is not obvious that the objects referenced by the 2 are indeed identical.